# Preferred way of initialization in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int i = 0; // (a) Old C style should I use it?
int i{0}; // (b) Brace direct init
int i{}; // (c) Same as (b)
int i = {0}; // (d) as (b)
int i = {}; // (e) as (c)
auto i = 0; // (f) auto = int in this case.
auto i = int{0}; // (g) auto = more specific.
auto i = int{}; // (h) same as above (g)
```

Which one to use?
Sutter says use:

```
int i = 0;
auto i = 0;
```

Why not:

```
int i = {0};
auto i = int{0};
```

And should I get rid of "=" in some cases:

```
int i{0};
auto i{0}; // i is not what some might expect in this case. So I would prefer using "=" everywhere possible like int i = {0}; ...
```

---

**EDIT:**
This is what I'm aiming for it seems to me the most consistent:

```
rectangle       w   = { origin(), extents() }; 
complex<double> c   = { 2.71828, 3.14159 }; 
mystruct        m   = { 1, 2 }; 
int             a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
vector<int>     v   = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
point           p   = {}; // Default initializes members
int             i   = {0}; // Checked assembly for this and it's binary the same as int i{0}; could be written also as int i = {};
string          s   = {""}; // Same as string s = {}; (OR) string s;
```

Real life examples:

```
std::string       title              = { pt.get<std::string>("document.window.title") };
const std::string file               = { R"(CoreSettings.xml)" };
int_least64_t     currentTick        = { 0 }; // (OR) int_least64_t currentTick = {};
bool              isRunning          = { false }; // (OR) bool isRunning = {};
App*              app                = { nullptr }; // (OR) App* app = {};
Event             event              = {};
double            detectedFrameRate  = { 1000000000.0 / (swapIntervalDeltaCumulative / 20.0) };
double            precision          = { static_cast<double>(boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num)
                                           / boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den };
auto              timeSpan           = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(nowTime - startTime);
```

Alternative would be:

```
std::string       title             { pt.get<std::string>("document.window.title") };
const std::string file              { R"(CoreSettings.xml)" };
int_least64_t     currentTick       { 0 }; // (OR) int_least64_t currentTick{};
bool              isRunning         { false }; // (OR) bool isRunning{};
App*              app               { nullptr }; // (OR) App* app{};
Event             event             {};
double            detectedFrameRate { 1000000000.0 / (swapIntervalDeltaCumulative / 20.0) };
double            precision         { static_cast<double>(boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num)
                                        / boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den };
auto              timeSpan          = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(nowTime - startTime);
```

If not using braces it's ugly or error-prone:

```
int_least64_t     currentTick        = 0; // C style - changed this from double to int recently and compiler did not complain so I had something like int_least64_t currentTick = 0.0; ugly!
bool              isRunning          = false; // C style
App*              app                = nullptr; // C mixed with C++11 style;
Event             event; // might not be initialized by all compilers
int               someInt            = func(); // func() returns double no error but narrowing.
```

Comment: Use the most idiomatic, least ambiguous and shortest one. That would be `int i = 0;` imo. To wit: `auto i{0};` defines a `std::initializer_list<int>`, not an `int`.

Comment: For the `ints` then `i = 0` and `i = {0}` are the same. It's only when you start dealing with other types that this distinction becomes more relevant. The reason I would advise against `auto i{0}` for an `int` is because now the reader needs to check if `i` was defined as a class. Instead by using `auto i = 0` they know that they are just dealing with an integer literal.

Comment: You can also do it like this: `int i = (2 * (5 + 27) * 91 * 2) % 4`

Comment: @Deduplicator: oh I didn't know it did that. That's very good to know!

Comment: This is too broad... it's basically a survey. There is no definitive answer just yet.

Comment: If you're looking for consistency, then I'm afraid you'll be disappointed. There are times when you must use brace-initialisation (e.g. `vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};` to initialise with element values) and times when you can't (e.g. `vector<int> v(2,42);` to choose another constructor). In general, try to make code as readable as possible, which doesn't mean imposing a weird sense of false consistency on it.

Comment: I do the same as I did in C++03, except for MVP cases and for constructs that were not possible in C++03.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For something simple, such as the `int` in your example, I'd agree that

```
int i=0;
```

is probably the most commonly understood (among programmers), but there are advantages to using the brace-initialization that, to me, make it preferable.  For instance

```
int i = 3.99;    // i gets 3; no warning, no error
int i{3.99};     // i gets 3; warning: "narrowing conversion"
```

It helps to write more bug-free code and is therefore a better way to do it in my view.

Mixing it with `auto` is more perilous.  I typically use `auto` only for:

- the temporary variable in a range-for loop (e.g. `for (const auto &n : mycollection)`)
- to simplify declaration of a named lambda
- for iterator instances when I use them explicitly (rather than range-for)
- templated code where doing so avoids creating a lengthy typedef

Comment: Welcome to initializer-list/uniform initialization hell.

Comment: But would you use int i = {3};? Just to stay consistent with auto i = int{0}; To me it's more readable to use = for init everywhere.

Comment: No, I would never use `int i={3}` because it's the worst of both worlds.  Either use `int i{3}` or, if the others reading your code aren't necessarily C++11 experts, `int i=3` since the latter syntax has been around since Algol60 and probably before.

Comment: @Edward: Why would you avoid using int i={3}; and why is it the worst of both worlds? int i = 0 is copy initialization with narrowing, the int i = {3}; is copy-list initialization without narrowing and most compilers optimize it to be int i{0}; direct initialization. So this way the "=" equal sign is only there for readability and the {} - braces prevent narrowing, also it looks more like int i = 0; but with braces.

Comment: @CrHasher: see my comment in response to Deduplicator's answer.

Comment: @Edward: Up-voted your answer because it seems to me that its the most relevant. I will go with uniform initialization syntax int i{0};

Answer (score 5):

There are some wrong derivations:

```
auto i{0}; // [comment omitted]
int i();
```

The first one defines `i` as a `std::initializer_list<int>`.
The second declares an extern function named `i` returning `int` and having no arguments.

Rules-of-thumb:

- Use `auto` where it saves typing and the type or its behavior is obvious. Examples:

  ```
  auto x = new mymegathingy;
  auto y = container.begin();
  auto z = filestream.seekoff(0, basic_ios::curr);
  ```
- Use assignment where that works (A potential temporary will be optimized away by any current compiler, possible when lhs and rhs have different types).

  ```
  int i = 0;
  int* i = 0; // For many types passing `nullptr` is better.
  ```
- Use universal initializer syntax where assignment does not work.

  ```
  std::vector<int> i = {1,2,3};
  auto i = new int[]{1,2,3};
  ```
- You might want to use direct constructor call where at least one obviously non-type argument is given, to avoid curly braces:

  ```
  int i(0);
  ```

Beware that initializing with universal initializer syntax mixes bad with `auto`, we get a `std::initializer_list<>`:

```
auto i{0};
```

Avoid old-style init wherever you do not pass at least one obvious non-type argument, otherwise you risk inadvertently declaring a function:

```
int i();
```

Comment: The advice to *use assignment where that works* might need clarification.  If we have `MyClass frank = 0`, we have, potentially (if the compiler isn't doing much optimization), creation of a temporary `MyClass` instance, followed by a move.  That's bypassed using the more direct `MyClass frank{0}`.

Comment: I prefer using int i = {0}; and std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3}; because if you write them one below the other it looks more consistent.

Comment: I'd omit the `=` in both of those statments.

Comment: Note that the committee is already considering [changing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) `auto i{0};` to deduce `int` instead (and ban `auto i{1, 2};` entirely).

Answer (score 1):

For the `int` type variables `i = 0` and `i = {0}` are the same. `int i = 0` will be the most readable as this is what people are used to seeing.

If you do go down the auto route you need to be aware of the fact that `auto i{0}` and `auto i = 0` are actually defining different types. (see Deduplicator's comment)

See this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(){
    auto a = 0;
    std::cout << "a is of type:" << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

    auto b = int{0};
    std::cout << "b is of type:" << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;

    auto c{0};
    std::cout << "c is of type:" << typeid(c).name() << std::endl;
}
```

When we run this we get:

```
a is of type:i
b is of type:i
c is of type:St16initializer_listIiE
```

The `auto c{0}` is actually creating a `std::initializer_list<int>` which is almost certainly not what was expected here by the person who posted the question.
Basically there are a bunch of potentially nasty things here when it comes to readability.

Here's something I just compiled with `g++ -Wall -std=c++11  main.cpp`  (g++ version 4.7.2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

class d{
    public:
        std::vector<int> v;
        d(std::initializer_list<int> l) : v(l) {
             std::cout << "constructed class d with a " << l.size() << "-element list\n";
        }
};

int main(){
    auto d{0};
    std::cout << "d is of type:" << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
}
```

When we run this we get:

```
d is of type:St16initializer_listIiE
```

This might not be what you expected either. Clearly if you are writing production code you would want to choose better class names, but I was surprised this gave no warnings when being compiled.

Comment: You are wrong when you say int i = 0; and int i = {0}; are the same. Consider the case int i = {0.0}, it's a compiler error. Even better is int i = { func() }; if func returns double compiler will give an error so it's safer no?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `int i = {0}` and `int i = {0.0}` are clearly different things.

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote there. Note that `int i = {0}` `!=` `int i{0.0}`. Further `int i = {func()}` is an entirely different case.

Comment: @shuttle87: Just wanted to know if we are on the same page with why int i = {0}; is better than int i = 0; in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Deduplicator.
I would use:

```
int i = 0;
```

It is the simplest, smallest, and most well known way of coding.

Comment: So is `free`, and that's insane to use.

Comment: Agree with Deduplicator. Keep it simple. You will find places where initializer list and auto are actually needed and serves a purpose. Until then, keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations are:

1) Use auto only for template constructions, where you can actually benefit from it and for iterators where type names may be long (if you prefer). Do not use it for primitive types, especially not references. If a function returns a reference and you want to use auto, you need to use auto&. If a not a copy is made, which can be quite tricky.

2) Think of code as someting that you can read on a piece of paper and be explicit about it. Do not try to hide types if they are fixed.

3) Initializer list can be dangerous. Use them when you need it. I have seen many structures, which are initialized using initializer lists and then a developer have added another member. With some compilers, no warnings are thrown (bummer).

Comment: If you cannot easily deduce from the surrounding code what auto means I'd say that is a problem with the code, rather than with auto. Typical example: of course using auto in a function of 100 lines doesn't make it any easier to understand what's going on. But the core problem there is obviously not the use of auto. Also please give us a reliable source of your claim that only noobs use mouseover in the debugger :P

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup uses Sam as his code editor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_(text_editor)#Endorsers  Sam doesn't support giving type information using mouseovers. He also says that in the unusual case when he does use an IDE that he wants "to be able to understand my system from just the source code in the source files." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500572.aspx Everyone else is a noob compared to Bjarne Stroustrup. Therefor only noobs use mouseover. QED.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I couldn't agree more. I use Emacs as my code editor, spent less than 5% of my time using an IDE and less than 1% of my time using a debugger.

Answer (score -2):

Use `auto name = initializer;` exclusively. There are a couple places where you need `auto&&` or `auto name = (Base*)initializer;`. And definitely do not ever use the curly braces because uniform initialization is broken as hell.

Comment: If your answer is intended solely to the case in which `auto` is being used, it would be helpful to mention it.  If not, it would be useful to elaborate on why, with an explicit type, you say that "uniform initialization is broken as hell."

Comment: I agree that we should almost always be using auto. I disagree that we should never use universal initialization. In particular, at a minimum, it's hard to find fault with doing so in an initializer list for a constructor. Also, use a C++ style cast.

Comment: Initializer lists and uniform init are two totally separate features, and the problems that occur when they interact are the primary reason for avoiding uniform initialization.